# Is it possible to take input of a string in c with format specifier %c without using loops

Tags: c

I know this code returns an error but is there anyway to input a string with %c format specifier **without the use of any loops?**

```
char string[100];
scanf("%c",&string);
```

Comment: Questions like this that ask about no loops always confuse me. First, you don't know if the library uses loops or not, so what difference does it make.  Second, here you've chose a format that inherently reads a single character and want to stick to that. (Instead of using `%s`, I guess.)  What's the real problem here?

Comment: "I know this code returns an error" How did you know? Your code invokes *undefined behavior* by passing data having wrong type to `scanf()` (`char(*)[100]` is passed where `char*` is expected), but typically this won't cause a problem other than being warned by the compiler.

Comment: Do you know what `%100c` would do?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use `%c` to input a string. If you add `[^\n]` between `%` and `c`, scanner will take input until a newline is found. Try the example code below:

```
char string[100]; 
scanf("%[^\n]c", string); // read characters until newline is found
```

If you want to scan a specific number of characters with `%c` you can add the number you want between `%` and `c`. Like if you want 5 characters to be inputted you can write it like this

```
char string[100]; 
scanf("%5c", string);
```

Remember this will break only after taking 5 character if you press enter after 3 character then a newline is also add to the string after 3 character. And it does not add endOfString('\0') automatically like `%s`. it only add the character you inputed

Comment: No, you cannot "add `[^\n]` between `%` and `c`" like this. (Well, you can, but it doesn't do what you might think.)

Comment: why not? the code is running and working fine in my codeblock ide.

Comment: Try it with just`%[^\n]` and see if it behaves any differently.  Then try it with `%[^\n]xyz`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can specify the number of characters to read with `%c` format specifier, so you can use that in a special case in which the length of the string to read is already known.

Also note that `%c` format specifyer doesn't put a terminating null-character, so you have to be careful not to forget to add that.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char string[100] = ""; /* initialize to put a terminating null-character */
    if (scanf("%10c", string) == 1) { /* read a 10-character string */
        puts(string);
    } else {
        fputs("read error\n", stderr);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "read a 10-character string" is more like "read 10-characters" as `scanf("%10c"...` does not involve a C _string_.

Comment: The terminating null character this implicitly alludes to is not read anyway.